# Avoiding to create a blank space when applying regex

Tags: node.js, regex, regex-group

I have the following regex:

```
result = result.replace(/\@.playhouse== 'true' && /g,'');
```

runs on

```
.playground[?(@.playhouse == 'true' && @.IsPoolAvailable=='true')].checked]
```

In my output I do get the expected response but it creates a space before `@` as shown below

```
.playground[?( @.IsPoolAvailable=='true')].checked]
```

Is there a way NOT to create that space by running only one regex exp? 
  See below:

```
.playground[?(@.IsPoolAvailable=='true')].checked]
```

Comment: I run it on my node. This result is correct as ```.playground[?(@.IsPoolAvailable=='true')].checked]```

Comment: For me, the result is .playground[?(  @.IsPoolAvailable=='true')].checked]             there is a visible space before @ which is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *escape* special characters, and then replace:

`@\.playhouse\s*==\s*'true'\s+&&\s+`

You get the output as expected:

[image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/We6sIy/4)